# Any reason to use external storage on Android anymore?

Tags: android

Early on, Android external storage (as available via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) actually stood for the physical removable card. My application goes back to 2011. When designing it back then, I made a point to place any potentially large files in the external storage, to save the precious device space.

These days, I don't have a large fleet of devices, but on all that I see the external storage is physically internal, not removable. Can't tell, though, if it's in the same filesystem as the data folder (as in `Context.getDir()`), i. e. are they under the shared space constraint.

Anyway, the question is - in 2019, does it still make sense to place large files into external storage as opposed to the data folder?

Comment: Many, if not most, modern Android phones have no physical external storage.

Comment: And yet Android goes through the trouble of emulating it, and even restricts access via permissions.

Comment: It's not actually meant to refer to physically external storage necessarily. Check the docs.

Comment: But it used to.

Comment: Not really. It's just the shared media folder for the current user (or device, before users), "external" from the app's private data.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway, the question is - in 2019, does it still make sense to place large files into external storage as opposed to the data folder?

The documentation covers why you would want to put things in internal or external storage depending on your use case:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#InternalVsExternalStorage